# set-up our own vertex id in titan using java API

Tags: java, bigdata, titan

I want to set up my own id to vertex like the way mentioned below.

```
BaseConfiguration configuration = new BaseConfiguration();
configuration.setProperty("storage.backend", "hbase");
configuration.setProperty("storage.hostname", "slave05");
configuration.setProperty("storage.port", "2181");
configuration.setProperty("storage.tablename", "REC_GRAPH1");
TitanGraph graph = TitanFactory.open(configuration);

Vertex vertex = graph.addVertex(200);
graph.commit();
```

But I'm not able to.. I guess I'm missing some configuration setup.

Please help me..

Thanks,
Vivek

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Titan assigns it's own identifiers.  You can not assign your own.  This behavior is typical of most graph databases (you will find this situation in nearly all [Blueprints](https://github.com/tinkerpop/blueprints) implementations).  If you have an identifier you wish to persist that is custom to you, you should create an appropriate index for fast lookup of that value and treat it as a property on your vertex.

Comment: It means you are saying we can have it as a property of that vertex (something like id=2)? We can't override the default vertex-id ?

Comment: You can't override the id and "id" itself is a reserved property name.  Just rename it to to something else and reference it as such (e.g. _id, uid, etc)