# Titan+Cassandra and String Vertex Ids

Tags: cassandra, titan, gremlin

It looks like we can get Titan 1.0 use custom long ids by setting "graph.set-vertex-id" to true. Is there some way to use non-long (i.e. String) ids as Vertex Ids? Seeing that the Tinkerpop api supports Strings, and there's a feature called "StringIds", is there some way of enabling that feature? I'm using Titan with Cassandra.

Answer (score 3):

I think this goes against Titan's internal structure. One of the Titan devs recommends [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17402716/1457059) to just use your own indexed property. This is reiterated [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/aureliusgraphs/Ud4jqGxsDF4) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22910013/set-up-our-own-vertex-id-in-titan-using-java-api) stating that unique indexed properties should be used.

I think the reason for this is that the internal ids actually refer to locations on the system. As stated [here](http://s3.thinkaurelius.com/docs/titan/1.0.0/data-model.html):

> The (64 bit) vertex id (which Titan uniquely assigns to every vertex) is the key which points to the row containing the vertex’s adjacency list.

Comment: hmm...that's surprising. Cassandra partition keys can be anything, and lookups would work just the same. And the Titan Apis, etc. (well Tinkerpop) suggests it should be possible. Then again, Titan uses the very old Thrift interface, and I'm thinking in CQL terms.

Answer (score 1):

No, String identifiers are not supported in the `StandardTitanGraph.features()`. You could consider using an indexed String property as an alternative.