# How to assign titan ids in titan db internal？

Tags: database, titan

I had view the source code of titan db, titan assign ids for vertex , property , label and so on. But it is difficult to understand how it works for assigning ？

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Titan+Cassandra and String Vertex Ids](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38229312/titancassandra-and-string-vertex-ids)

Answer (score 1):

A Titan ID have the following format

```
╔═════════╦═══════════╦══════════════════╗
║ Counter ║ Partition ║   IDTypePadding  ║
╚═════════╩═══════════╩══════════════════╝
```

- Every ID has `IDTypePadding` suffix. Suffix define type of ID. This is implemented in `IDManager` class `VertexIDType` enum.
- By default there are 32 partition value available. Each titan instance by default randomly choose 10 partition.
- For each partition, titan allocate ID Block. Default ID Block size is 10000. Titan make sure, ID block is unique across cluster at partition level using Backend Storage's `titan_ids` table.
- ID Assigning : First titan select the `IDTypePadding`. then choose a partition randomly. At last get the incremented counter from the ID Block.